# Hot to configure metro for UI Kitten build in EAS CI?

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to use [`@ui-kitten/metro-config`](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/improving-performance#improving-performance) with the new EAS build flow from Expo.

Everything works well when I build an app for development and serve it through a development client. However, when I build a standalone version, the custom mapping I defined through my `mapping.json` does not get applied.

The documentation linked above says that one would have to run a CLI command before building in a CI environment: `ui-kitten bootstrap @eva-design/eva ./path-to/mapping.json`. But I can't figure out where to place this command so that it gets executed on EAS build servers at the right time.

Here is a reproducible example: https://github.com/acrdlph/expo-mcve/tree/ui-kitten - in `development` builds (which depend on a dev client) the `h1` size is re-defined according to the `mapping.json`. In the `preview` and `production` profiles the `h1` tag defaults back to its normal size.

Grateful for all pointers!

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue. There seems to be an bug in the metro-configuration and the .json mapping, or it might be expected behavior, I am not entirely sure. I fixed it by applying the custom mapping.json in both the ApplicationProvider as:

```
     import { default as theme } from './theme.json'; 
     import { default as mapping} from './mapping.json';
     ....
     <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.dark, ...theme }} customMapping={mapping}>
      <HomeScreen />
     </ApplicationProvider>
```

And the metro.config.js file as:

```
const path = require('path');
const MetroConfig = require('@ui-kitten/metro-config');
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const evaConfig = {
   evaPackage: '@eva-design/eva',
   customMappingPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'mapping.json'),};

module.exports = MetroConfig.create(evaConfig,config);
```

I found some insight in this issue https://githubhot.com/repo/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/1568